# Dividing a number into smaller random ints

Tags: java, random, divide

So what i need is basically described in the subject.

Like if i would put in number 12 and amount of parts it should devide into, i would like it to return something like (with 4 parts) 8, 2, 1, 1. But not doubles because i need the values as int.
I had found one answer earlier but it only worked using doubles. not ints.
(this is the one i found)

```
public double[] divideUniformlyRandomly(double number, int part) {
    double uniformRandoms[] = new double[part];
    Random random = new Random();
    double mean = number / part;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<part / 2; i++) {
        uniformRandoms[i] = random.nextDouble() * mean;
        uniformRandoms[part - i - 1] = mean + random.nextDouble() * mean;
        sum += uniformRandoms[i] + uniformRandoms[part - i -1];
    }
    uniformRandoms[(int)Math.ceil(part/2)] = uniformRandoms[(int)Math.ceil(part/2)] + number - sum;
    return uniformRandoms;
```

I had tried changing this code to work using Ints by doing this:

```
public int[] divide(int number) {
    int part = getDivider(number);
    int uniformRandoms[] = new int[part];
    Random random = new Random();
    int mean = number / part;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<part / 2; i++) {
        uniformRandoms[i] = random.nextInt() * mean;
        uniformRandoms[part - i - 1] = mean + random.nextInt() * mean;
        sum += uniformRandoms[i] + uniformRandoms[part - i -1];
    }
    uniformRandoms[(int)Math.round(part/2)] = uniformRandoms[(int)Math.round(part/2)] + number - sum;
    for(int i : uniformRandoms)
        System.out.println(i);
    return uniformRandoms;
}
```

But when running that using number: 512 and using 10 parts (getDivider() will return 10) itll output this:

```
-1058809647, -2102647561, 469849949, 1627965716, -290084223, -33347991
```

And alot more of this kind of numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: If you need ints, use `nextInt`.

Comment: @AntonH, thats what i tried doing in the first place, but that returned rediculous values (like i putted in 10 and parts 4 and it would return like 20 million, 40 million, 20 million, 25 million)      @

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to achieve. Particularly, you said nothing about the distribution of the numbers. Would it be OK to split `1000000` into `[999995, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`? Would it be OK to split `50` into `[10,10,10,10,10]`? Or to put it that way: **What** exactly should be random?

Comment: Both of those would be OK, just as long as the returned values are random and their sum being the inputted number.

Comment: You didn't do anything to tell `Random` to generate a number between 1 and `mean` (or 0 and `mean-1` or anything like that).  Therefore it generated a number in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647.  Check the [documentation of `Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every term should at least be 1.

```
public int[] divide(int number, int parts) {
    int[] randoms = new int[parts];
    Arrays.fill(randoms, 1); // At least one
    int remainder = number - parts;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < parts - 1 && remainder > 0; ++i) {
        int diff = random.nextInt(remainder);
        randoms[i] += diff;
        remainder -= diff;
   }
   randoms[parts - 1] += remainder;
   Arrays.sort(randowms);

   // Reverse (for getting a descending array):
   for (int i = 0, j = parts - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {h
       int temp = randoms[i];
       randoms[i] = randoms[j];
       randoms[j] = temp;
   }
   return randoms;
}
```

This is *not* uniformly distributed. For that one could iterate till remainder becomes 0, everytime randomly picking an index to increase. Or so. Have fun.

*Was this homework?*

Comment: Thanks! you made one lil eror in the code tho, and yeah it was part of homework. I would upvote but i dont have 15 rep points >.<    Edit* i see u already patched up that error ;p.

Comment: Nice seeing you were actively reading the code; I hope some code patterns were interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Random#nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

```
public int[] divideUniformlyRandomly(int number, int parts) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] randoms = new int[];
    for(int i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
        randoms[randoms.length] = random.nextInt(number);
    }
    return randoms;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wont actually return numbers with the sum of number right?

Comment: @user2078401 From the javadoc page I linked: "Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)"

Comment: So nextInt(10) will return any number in the range 0 to 9

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm which will do the job:

1. Create an array of length `parts+1`.
2. Add the values 0 and `number` to the array, then fill the remainder of
   it with **unique** random values using `random.nextInt(number-1) + 1`
   to get values between 0 and `number` exclusive of the range limits.
3. Sort the array.
4. Iterate through the sorted array starting at index 1. The successive
   differences `array[i] - array[i-1]` will be a set of positive integers that
   sum to `number`.

If zeros are allowed, then you don't need the uniqueness criterion in filling the array.
If you need uniqueness, you might consider adding random values to a `HashSet` (which only `.add()`'s unique entries) until the size meets your requirement, then convert it with `.toArray()`.

Here's an actual implementation:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class SumToTotal {
   public static Random r = new Random();

   public static int[] divide(int number, int number_of_parts) {
      HashSet<Integer> uniqueInts = new HashSet<Integer>();
      uniqueInts.add(0);
      uniqueInts.add(number);
      int array_size = number_of_parts + 1;
      while (uniqueInts.size() < array_size) {
         uniqueInts.add(1 + r.nextInt(number - 1));
      }
      Integer[] dividers = uniqueInts.toArray(new Integer[array_size]);
      Arrays.sort(dividers);
      int[] results = new int[number_of_parts];
      for(int i = 1, j = 0; i < dividers.length; ++i, ++j) {
         results[j] = dividers[i] - dividers[j];
      }
      return results;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(divide(12, 5)));
   }
}
```

This produces results such as `[3, 2, 1, 2, 4]` or `[1, 5, 2, 3, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

A inefficient but very easy way would be to loop n times and increment one of the indices by one.

```
    void divider(int number, int divisions)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] container = new int[divisions];

        System.out.print(number + "->");
        while (number > 0)
        {
            container[rand.nextInt(divisions)]++;
            number--;
        }
        for (int i : container)
        {
            System.out.print("[" + i + "]");
        }
    }
```

`divider(1000, 20)` could output:

```
1000->[57][43][60][35][39][47][45][59][51][71][52][54][58][48][33][49][49][46][49][55]
1000->[60][50][49][53][42][52][52][45][40][51][52][51][53][47][51][46][53][56][45][52]
1000->[52][43][49][53][57][45][42][43][61][61][58][44][46][49][52][39][63][45][54][44]
```

On my way to old PC it takes only 11ms to divide `100.000` in 20 different "containers". So if you are not using this very often and/or on very big numbers this is a perfectly valid way to do it.